# Does Alien Fuel Refinery count as having a trade power in Race for the Galaxy?

Tags: race-for-the-galaxy

In Race for the Galaxy, does the Alien Fuel Refinery restriction ("you may not trade a good from this world") count as a "trade power" for the purposes of Trade League, or in other words do I score a point for having Alien Fuel Refinery in my tableau if I also play Trade League?

It seems a bit strange to me that Trade League gives you points for not being able to trade, but (unless I've miscounted) Keldon's AI thinks that it does. Is there anything more official out there as a ruling on this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does count. The [Alien Artifact rules](http://riograndegames.com/getFile.php?id=1813) actually cover this!

> Consume powers, such as Trade League’s power, can be used. 
>   Trade League and Wormhole Prospectors do score for this world.

Similarly, the [Brink of War rules](http://riograndegames.com/getFile.php?id=506) explicitly state that Trade League does score for the can't sell power of Alien Oort Cloud Refinery (bottom of page 13)

Answer (score -1):

It has a trading power, the restriction is that you have to trade goods from other worlds. This could be done to restrict the card from being to good, or it balances with higher VP-score or lower cost to attack/buy.

In this specific case, the reason that you cannot trade its own good is probably because it is cheap, or, that the designers wanted a cheap producing alien world.

It produces a yellow good which combined with a trading power is a really good combination.

Comment: "If it has a trading power, it has a trading power". Is that an official ruling, or your interpretation?

Comment: It does indeed keep the card from being too good. But that's pretty separate from whether it's a trade power. It sounds like you've never even seen the card?

Comment: @PhilipKendall - It has a trading power. It is right there on the card. You can use it to trade. And Google is my friend (Image wise that is). Edited to make the answer less ambiguous.

Comment: Either I (and Keldon's AI) are massively misinterpreting the meaning of the card, or you are; you *cannot* use the trade power to trade in any way - it explicitly stops you from selling the good from Alien Fuel Refinery when you select the "Consume - Trade" action (or, I guess get a trade option in some other way like Black Market Trading World or Trade League, but I haven't tested that in the AI).

Comment: @TobiasWärre Philip is completely correct here. You *can't* use the power to trade. All the power does is keep you from trading (from this world). You can still trade goods from other worlds (it doesn't prevent that), but it has nothing to do with this card; that's just normal trading.

Comment: You can use Trade League and Black Market Trading World on the Alien Fuel Refinery good.